# I want to take take samples at midpoint of a square wave ?

Tags: matlab

```
t=0:0.001:8;
x=square(pi*t,50);
y = awgn(x,4);
plot (t,x+y);
axis ([0 8 -1 1]);
xlabel ('Time');
ylabel ('Amplitude');
grid on;
```

this is the code in which i have added noise to a square wave .
Now I want to take samples at the midpoints.

Comment: What?????????????????????????????????

Comment: How to take samples at midpoints like if we have a cycle starting from 0 to T. How can I sample it at T/2??

Answer (score 0):

Use linear interpolation, `calcY = interp1q(t,y,t2)`. `t2` would be your t value for the midpoint. `calcY` would be the sample value at the midpoint, estimated using linear interpolation. The link for the `interplq` function is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1q.html).